# Check the convergence of $a_n=\frac{n^2 }{ ( (2n)! )^{ \frac{1}{n} } }$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

How to check the convergence of the sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$, where 
$$ a_n \colon= \frac{n^2 }{ ((2n)!)^{\frac{1}{n} } } $$
for each $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

I've tried to use the ratio test for this sequence. My intuition is the sequence converges to $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may write
$$
a_n  = \sqrt[n]{{\frac{{n^{2n} }}{{(2n)!}}}} = \sqrt[n]{{b_n }}.
$$
Now you can use the general implication that
$$
\frac{{b_{n + 1} }}{{b_n }} \to L \Rightarrow \sqrt[n]{{b_n }} \to L.
$$
Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{{b_{n + 1} }}{{b_n }} &= \frac{{\frac{{(n + 1)^{2n + 2} }}{{(2n + 2)!}}}}{{\frac{{n^{2n} }}{{(2n)!}}}} \\ 
&= \frac{{(n + 1)^2 }}{{(2n + 2)(2n + 1)}}\left[ {\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^n } \right]^2 \\
&= \left[ \frac{ (n + 1) }{ 2 (2n + 1)  } \right] \times \left[ {\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^n } \right]^2 \\
&= \frac{ 1 + \frac{1}{n} }{ 2 \left( 2 + \frac{1}{n} \right) } \times \left[ {\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^n } \right]^2 .
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

By [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), you have$$(2n)!\approx\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}e\right)^{2n}$$and therefore$$\sqrt[n]{(2n)!}\approx\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{4\pi n}}\left(\frac{2n}e\right)^2.$$Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

note here that $a_n=\bigg\{\frac{n^{2n}}{(2n)!}\bigg\}^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and let $b_n=\frac{n^{2n}}{(2n)!}$

now, use $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=\frac{(n+1)^{2(n+1)}.(2n)!}{2(n+1)!.n^{2n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+\frac{1}{n})^{2n}(n+1)}{2(2n+1)}=\frac{e^2}{4}$. so by cauchy's second principle on limit , it is the required limit for $\{{a_n}\}$ too.

Comment: You call $a_n$ two different sequences.

Comment: sorry, that was a typing mistake, will fix soon

Answer (score 0):

Consider $[n^{2n}]^{\frac 1n } = n^2 $ and also $n^{2n}$ means that n is $2n$ terms of $n$ are multiplied together.

Next consider $\frac {2n!} {n^{2n}} $ this can be simplified as
$$= \frac {2n}n * \frac {(2n-1)}n *...*\frac {n}n * \frac {(n-1)}n *...* \frac {1}n $$
Rearranging the above sequence we get
$$= [\frac {2n}n *\frac {1}n]* [\frac {(2n-1)}n* \frac {2}n ]*[\frac {(2n-2)}n * \frac {3}n *]...  $$ 
$$= \frac {2n}{n^2} *\frac {(2n-1)2}{n^2}*\frac {(2n-2)}{n^2}* ...  $$

But as $n \to \infty$ , $\frac an \to 0$ for any finite number $a$

By that logic we can reduce the above equation to
$$\approx \frac {2n}{n^2} *\frac {(2n)2}{n^2}*\frac {(2n)3}{n^2}* ...\frac {(n+1)n}{n^2} $$
Therefore;
$$\frac {2n!} {n^{2n}} \approx \frac {{2^k}{(1*2*3*...*n)}}{n}$$
where $ k \in\Re$ and $n\gt k \ge 1$

Hence $$\frac {2n!} {n^{2n}} \gt 1$$
 $$\big(\frac {2n!}{n^{2n}}\big )^{1/n} \gt 1$$
Therefore
$${(2n!)}^{1/n} \gt n^2 $$

Therefore the series should be convergent.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_n=\frac{n^2 }{ ( (2n)! )^{ \frac{1}{n} } }\implies \log(a_n)=2 \log (n)-\frac{1}{n}\log ((2 n)!)$$

Use Stirling approximation to get
$$\log(a_n)=2(1-\log (2))-\frac{\log (4 \pi  n)}{2 n}-\frac{1}{24 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)} \implies a_n \sim \frac{1}{4} e^{2-\frac{\log (4 \pi  n)}{2 n}}\to \frac{e^{2}}{4} $$